# How to extract these texts?

Tags: php, list, text, extract, cpu-word

I want to extract this elements from this text:

Thu, Nov 12, 2020 at 12:15 PM
Thu, Nov 12, 2020 at 12:15 PM
bladberi@postdreifing.is bladberi@postdreifing.is Thu, Nov 12, 2020 at 12:15 PM To: martimehf@gmail.com, bladberi@postdreifing.is
**109/06 Fornistekkur 11** MBL. did not come. - **Elisabet Kemp**
bladberi@postdreifing.is bladberi@postdreifing.is Thu, Nov 12, 2020 at 12:15 PM To: martimehf@gmail.com, bladberi@postdreifing.is
**109/06 Fomistekkur 8** MBL. did not come. - **Sæmundur Guðmundsson**
bladberi@postdreifing.is bladberi@postdreifing.is Thu, Nov 12, 2020 at 12:44 PM To: martimehf@gmail.com, bladberi@postdreifing.is

Is it possible somehow?

Maybe someone have idea how to extract highlighted text only this from .txt file with php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start, hope helps...

```
$str = "Thu, Nov 12, 2020 at 12:15 PM Thu, Nov 12, 2020 at 12:15 PM bladberi@postdreifing.is bladberi@postdreifing.is Thu, Nov 12, 2020 at 12:15 PM To: martimehf@gmail.com, bladberi@postdreifing.is 109/06 Fornistekkur 11 MBL. did not come. - Elisabet Kemp bladberi@postdreifing.is bladberi@postdreifing.is Thu, Nov 12, 2020 at 12:15 PM To: martimehf@gmail.com, bladberi@postdreifing.is 109/06 Fomistekkur 8 MBL. did not come. - Sæmundur Guðmundsson bladberi@postdreifing.is bladberi@postdreifing.is Thu, Nov 12, 2020 at 12:44 PM To: martimehf@gmail.com, bladberi@postdreifing.is";


 $pattern = array ("/\d{3}\/\d{2} [a-zA-Z0-9]* [0-9]{1,2}/");
 $replacement =  array ('<strong>$0</strong>');

 echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

If you wish to extract....

```
$pattern = "/\d{3}\/\d{2} [a-zA-Z0-9]* [0-9]{1,2}/";

$matches = array();
preg_match_all ($pattern, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: It's good, thanks. How to remove text in echo and leave only highlighted?